# How do i log all logging output to a file with wildcards if i run the build from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

There are plenty of posts on how to capture logging output while manually invoking msbuild from the console but i am wondering if there is any way to log all logging output to a file of my desire using wildcards (timestamps, Configuration etc) if the build is fired from Visual Studio.

No - running it from console is not an option. I've spent 2 days trying to get it to work. Seems like the Xamarin targets were not built with dev friendly build automation in mind.

Why is it not an option?
- Wrong toolset, 
- wrong MSBuild, 
- mtouch warnings, 
- targets which expect env variables which seem to be added by VS at runtime

so i gave up and am looking for a way to capture my logs so i can dump the output into a file together with other artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

> How do i log all logging output to a file with wildcards if i run the build from visual studio

According to the [How to: View, Save, and Configure Build Log Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj651643.aspx):

> After you build a project in the Visual Studio IDE, you can view
>   information about that build in the **Output** window. By using this
>   information, you can, for example, troubleshoot a build failure. For
>   C++ projects, you can also view the same information in a .txt file
>   that's created and saved automatically. For managed-code projects, you
>   can copy and paste the information from the **Output** window into a .txt
>   file and save it yourself. You can also use the IDE to specify what
>   kinds of information you want to view about each build.
>
> If you build
>   any kind of project by using MSBuild, you can create a .txt file to
>   save information about the build. For more information, see [Obtaining
>   Build Logs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171470.aspx).

We could to know log file from Visual Studio is only supported for C++ projects. we have to work with the output window for others.

If you do not want to copy and pasting the content to a text file.  Here is a quiets way to avoid copy past and save the content directly:

Follow these steps:
1. Set the focus to the Output Window
2. From the main menu navigate to  File –> Save Selected Items (Ctrl + S) or Save Output As.

To save the content directly in to a text file.

[image]

Default filename will have the name with “Output-Build”, you can change it to what you want, but it could not use wildcards in the name.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: doesn't help unfortunately. i know how to automate it with manually invoking msbuild. i particularly need automated log files from within VS. Guess i'll see if a build task can do that. Thanks for trying anyway

Comment: Yes, if you want to automate log files from vs, you may need find a task to do it. But after check the Visual Studio API for output windows, IVsOutputWindow Interface & IVsOutputWindowPane Interface https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsoutputwindowpane.aspx, there is no that method to do it. But I am not very sure if there is any other magic here. As suggestion you can open a new thread with VSX tag.